# WSO2 AM 1.10.0 -- Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I deployed WSO2 Am to a production server in my organization and APIs can be accessed from organization's intranet through both http and https, (http://puaki.mpi.govt.nz/api/mrldatabase/v1/countries and https://puaki.mpi.govt.nz/api/mrldatabase/v1/countries). However, when trying to access APIs from outside internet, it is hitting an issue, `I/O error: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported`

[image: Connection_error]

Could anyone please help me solve the issue?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

it should be enabled by default , however you can configure Transport level security as described in this doc :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security